# User registration for with photo upload, get ERROR when user doesn't upload photo

Tags: php, forms, upload, registration, photo

I have a user registration form that now has photo upload capability. However, when a user doesn't upload a photo (very often), I get errors. But I want to be able to give the option to users NOT to upload a photo if they don't want to.

However, it still inserts all the other values in the database.

ERRORS:
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /mounted-storage/home94c/sub005/sc13306-UHPW/tvproductionguide.com/add.php on line 25

and

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mounted-storage/home94c/sub005/sc13306-UHPW/tvproductionguide.com/add.php:25) in /mounted-storage/home94c/sub005/sc13306-UHPW/tvproductionguide.com/add.php on line 35

I am very new in PHP and probably made several mistakes when coding (please, excuse my code).

The form is simple and should be alright. I'm not posting it here, unless someone needs to see it.
The PHP page code is:

```
<?php include 'configdb.php'; 

 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
 $position=$_POST['position'];
 $bio=$_POST['bio'];
 $experience=$_POST['experience'];
 $city=$_POST['city'];
 $phone=$_POST['phone'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $website=$_POST['website'];

if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
    }else{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

            $photo_location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
            $caption=$_POST['caption'];

            $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO miamicrew (name, last_name, position, bio, experience, city, phone, email, website, photo_location, caption) VALUES ('$name','$last_name','$position','$bio','$experience','$city','$phone','$email', '$website','$photo_location','$caption')");
            header("location: added.php");
            exit();                 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (!isset($_POST['image'])) {
 $photo_location="";
        $caption="";


}else{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $photo_location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $caption=$_POST['caption'];

        $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO miamicrew (name, last_name, position, bio, experience, city, phone, email, website, photo_location, caption) VALUES ('$name','$last_name','$position','$bio','$experience','$city','$phone','$email', '$website','$photo_location','$caption')");
        header("location: added.php");
        exit();                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is messy and totally not thought through. Here's what it should be like to give the desired effect.

```
if(strlen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) > 0)
{
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Error";
        exit();
    }

    $photo_location = "photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
} 
else 
{  
    $photo_location="";
    $caption = $_POST['caption'];
}


$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO miamicrew (name, last_name, position, bio, experience, city, phone, email, website, photo_location, caption) VALUES ('$name','$last_name','$position','$bio','$experience','$city','$phone','$email', '$website','$photo_location','$caption')");

header("location: added.php");
exit();
```